# Problems with using .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I wanted to play with new features of .NET and C#.

In order to do that, I downloaded newest .NET SDK and .NET runtime and installed it successfully.

Then I tried to create app with new features and failed, as I couldn't set target framework to .NET 5.

So I googled for that and found that I need to enable "using previews of .NET SDKs" in Visual Studio's Tools (Preiview Features tab).

After that, when I created console project, it set my target framework to .NET 5.0, I got this section in my csproj:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

Now, when I try to build, I get this error:

> The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

I tried to search anything about this, but I just run into the same articles suggesting enabling using preivew of .NET Core SDKs.

Also, my VS version is VS Studio Professional 16.7.6 (as far as I remember, other suggestions were about updateing VS to 16.6 or newer).

Comment: if you just use the visual studio updater to update to 16.8 it will install .net 5 etc for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of development with Visual Studio, .NET 5 requires VS 2019 16.8 or later. I'm using it with .NET 5 without problems.